# I can't find the location of jdk for Java 7 and 8

Tags: macos, java

I have 3 different versions (jdk) of Java installed: 6, 7 and 8. In bash_profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
setjdk() {
  export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v $1)
}
```

However, at

```
$ ls /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
1.6.0.jdk
```

I see only one version. Where are the 2 other ones? What's the location of their jdks?